# How to exclude self linking pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, page-views

The situation I'm having is that if you are on the home page '/' and you click on the 'Home' link or the logo (which takes you to 'Home'), it counts as a pageview. How would I go around excluding this sort of behaviour?

In general, I'm looking for a way to exclude all self-linking pageviews – excludes all pageviews of links that takes you to the same page.

Comment: *it counts as a pageview* is perfectly normal. The question is *how* are you seeing this? In Google Analytics? In your log file analyzer? Where? Otherwise, there is nothing we can say to help you. Cheers!

Comment: When using the analytics plugin for chrome, you can see percentages allocated for these links. I would like to exclude such measurements from being counted as pageviews. If you are on the homepage (eg. index.html) and you click on the 'Home' link, which is index.html, it should not be counted. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: I have not idea about any plug-in. With log file analyzers and likely too with Google Analytics, you should be able to write some kind of filter rule. I have no idea. I just thought that without understanding what you were looking at, it would impossible to answer the question. Cheers!!